# Plan a task multiple times

Tags: ms-project-2013

I want to make some form of recurring task that will occur after specified other tasks.

Instead of every x days/weeks/etc. occur after Task X, Y and Z (self specified)

Any help would be appreciated, I figured I'd try and ask here before making four duplicate task groups after task X, Y and Z.

(I'm not a projectmanager, but a programmer who has to make a planning for development in MS-project)

Cheers.

EDIT:
In this case X, Y and Z are functionalities that are to be built into a product.

- Develop the function to request time off (X)
- Test function X
- Roll out new version with X
- Develop Reports for management (Y)
- Test function Y
- Roll out new version with Y
- Develop Sending mails in outlook to a user (Z)
- Test function Z
- Roll out new version with Z

See what I mean with a repeating task?

I would like to make it into a repeating task, that comes after the developing of a functionality, without having three times the same task. (redundancy is bad in programming, hence I wondered if there was a way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS-Project does not have the functionality you require, unfortunately.

Nor are they the same tasks just because they deliver the same logical outcomes (tested something) using the same logical process (test something). You require a level of abstraction that does not exist in the product.

Just stick with manual tasks, the overhead to your effort and maintenance is minimal.

Comment: Right answer here. These are different tasks with different data attributes you need to collect: costs, resource sizing and skills, etc. Don't cheap out. Build your schedule so it is a meaningful management tool versus a simple checklist of to dos.

Comment: You're right and I have incorporated a few cycles of testing. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you over-planning the project and under planning the task process? Could you put in your process documentation that this task always occur after you do xyz? For instance, after every test cycle, there is a test after-action meeting. The test may not always be the same, but the process of testing generally is. That after-action meeting may be included in the test plan and execution process as a mandatory step. Does this make sense? Also, what tier in the project WBS is this repeated task? Depending on how low in the WBS this task is, it could be included in the project management plan if at a high level or the process steps at the low level.

Comment: Edited my question to make it more clear what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar by referencing external projects.  I have repetitive tasks that have one fixed deadline and a dozen other events that reference that deadline directly or indirectly (Task 1 must complete on date X; task 2 must begin 10 days after X, task 3 must complete 13 days before X, etc.)

I create a template for the tasks with all the right relationships and then I copy the template make appropriate adjustments and then "include" the template in my project plan. 
If you can find the API for "include" you might be able to do what you want.